# How to compute the homology group of $SO(n)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

How to compute the homology group of $SO(n)$?

I can calculate the homology group of $SO(n)$ when $n\leq3$.eg,$SO(3)\cong RP^3$,but I have no idea when $n>4$.I tried to use the exact sequence of relative homology group.What is the homology of $H_n(SO(n)\setminus\{I_n\})$?

Comment: The integral homology is quite tricky; see http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002240499190108E. The rational homology is much easier.

Comment: You might also like to compute the mod 2 homology. Hatcher does this at around page 296.

Comment: How to compute the relative integral homology$H_q(SO(n),SO(n)\setminus\{I_n\})$